# What is the difference between these functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to know which is the difference between these expressions:

**case a:**

```
const functionA = () => {
   executeA(), executeB()
}
```

**case b:**

```
const functionA = () => {
  executeA();
  executeB();
}
```

Comment: Personal opinion, but I'd say that the first one is just trying to be clever for no reason.  The comma operator has a purpose, and its purpose isn't used there.  Better to just invoke each function as its own statement for clarity.  (If there's a linter configuration to warn on expressions with ignored results, I'd recommend enabling it.)

Comment: The first version is a way less readable way to do the same thing used by people who like to write "optimized" code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do exactly the same thing, but the first one is weird and the second one is the normal way of writing code.
Don't use the first version.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is an expression that uses [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

The other one is two statements.

There is no difference between these two in this situation.